# Unity 3D Trying To Disable Joystick Controls So The Character Can't Move While Aiming

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, joystick

I'm trying to disable the joystick controls so when I zoom in on my character(and he is aiming), he won't start to move if the player accidently hits the joystick while he is in aim mode.

I'm using the --new input system from the starter assets (action type/passthrough & control type/Vector2)-- and I'm using a locomotion blend tree (2D free form Directional as the blend type)

(The two lines below are what I want to disable)

```cs
playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();    
        playerControls.PlayerMovement.Camera.performed += i => cameraInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (playerControls == null)
        {
            playerControls = new PlayerControls();

            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();    
            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Camera.performed += i => cameraInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();

            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Run.performed += i => runInput = true; /// Hold
            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Run.canceled += i => runInput = false; /// Let Go

            playerControls.PlayerMovement.QuickTurn.performed += i => QuickTurnInput = true;

            playerControls.PlayerActions.Aim.performed += i => aimingInput= true; 
            playerControls.PlayerActions.Aim.canceled += i => aimingInput = false;

            playerControls.PlayerActions.Shoot.performed += i => shootInput = true;
            playerControls.PlayerActions.Shoot.canceled += i => shootInput = false;
        }

        playerControls.Enable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is for you to disable movement while aim was performed like this:

```
playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue() && playerControler.PlayerActions.Aim.performed;
playerControls.PlayerMovement.Camera.performed += i => cameraInput = i.ReadValue() && playerControler.PlayerActions.Aim.performed;
```

You can try it, but move this snippet below your Aim.performed snippet

Comment: I tried it but i get an error where it says Aim.performed

Comment: Can you fully disclose the error?

Comment: the error says "The inputAction.performed can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for the most part. here is what I used

```
    if (playerManager.isAiming)
        {
            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = Vector2.zero;
        }
        else
        {
            playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        }
```

unfortunately I had a boolean that I forgot to disable so that is what gave me most of my problems.